# How do you make Azure storage (blob) work?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I used Azure blob to store images. I tested on local machine (with emulator) and it works. As you know, it uses URI like

```
http://127.0.0.1/xxx
```

But after I deployed to Azure, it doesn't work. I have

(1) changed the StorageConnectionString to point to Azure blob (instead of local emulated blob)

(2) changed blob access from 'off' to 'container'

(3) linked this blob to my website

I cannot think of anything else I need to do to make it work.

Can anyone help me?

**Edit:**

More information:

on local:

```
<add key="StorageConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=devstoreaccount1;AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==;BlobEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1" />
```

on Azure:

```
<add key="StorageConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=[myAccount];AccountKey=[myKey];BlobEndpoint=http://[myBolbName].blob.core.windows.net/" />
```

The error on Azure is (when I click a button to upload an image):

```
Application: 2014-05-09T07:45:12  PID[22228] Error       Unable to connect to the remote server
Application:    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext)
Application:    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob.UploadFromStreamHelper(Stream source, Nullable`1 length, AccessCondition accessCondition, BlobRequestOptions options, OperationContext operationContext)
Application:    at xxx.Utility.AzureStorageAccess.UploadBlob(Stream stream, String containerName, String blobRelativeURI, String& blobURI)
Application:    at xxx.xxx.xxx.btnSubmit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Comment: You could help yourself by showing some code.

Comment: If you're linking to images from your website, you might need to be looking at [Azure CDN](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cdn-how-to-use/)

Comment: @BrendanGreen - not sure why you're bringing up CDN - that has nothing to do with the question, as the question is not asking about optimizing latency of public blob access when clients are geo-distributed. The question (while poorly illustrated) is about the proper use of blob URI's.

Comment: @martial - All you said is *it doesn't work.* We don't even know what that means. As John said: show your code. Show an actual URI you're using (masking out your unique namespace). Show the results, or error. Show *something.* As it stands, your question isn't answerable.

Comment: @DavidMakogon: (3) linked this blob to my website.  With no code demonstrating the issue, mentioning Azure CDN is not unreasonable.

Comment: Wrap the code in a try / catch and log account, key and the URL you're trying to write to to make sure you're writing to a valid blob storage location and using valid credentials.  You can log to Azure Diagnostic (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg433048.aspx) or you could just output it on screen for debug purposes if you can't get Diagnostics working (it needs table storage access).

Comment: Sometimes corporate firewall rules may prevent access. Can you verify that this is not the issue?

Comment: @Simon W, thank you. following your suggestion I found the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The URI to point to a blob in Storage is:

`http://{accountName}.blob.core.windows.net/{container}/{blobName}`

So, if your storage account is called `marvin`, the container is called `images` and the blob name is `banner.png`, the URI will be

`http://marvin.blob.core.windows.net/images/banner.png`

Note that unless you want people to be able to list the blobs within the container, you should set the public access level to `blob`, which makes the blobs visible but prevents operations on the container itself.

Also, for browsers to work correctly with the image, you'll need to ensure you've set the ContentType property on each blob to the correct MIME type, e.g. `image/png`.

Comment: You should be using account name in this url `BlobEndpoint=http://[myBolbName].blob.core.windows.net/` instead of 'myBlobName`. So your Blob endpoint should be `http://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/`.

Answer (score 1):

Thank Simon W for his comment, when I start to wrap the code with try and catch, I found the problem.

I have the following in my code:

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("UseDevelopmentStorage=true");
```

I use this since I read somewhere that to make blob work in local, you need to use "UseDevelopmentStorage=true".

But this apparently doesn't work when deploy to Azure. So I have to replace it with:

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse([my-real-storage-connection-string]);
```

where `[my-real-storage-connection-string]` is

```
"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=[myAccount];AccountKey=[myKey];BlobEndpoint=http://[myBolbName].blob.core.windows.net/"
```

This works.